# Powermock : Mocked method still called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermock

First of all, please know that I've searched SO before asking this question, but I was unable to find a satisfying answer.

I'm using JUnit4 and Powermock 1.5.5 (with mockito 1.9.5)

My problem is the following : in my unit tests, I need to mock a static method in a class I can't modify. I only want to mock one method, and not the whole class, so I went for a spy.

Here's what I have so far :

```
[...]
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext-test.xml"},
    loader=MockWebApplicationContextLoader.class)
@MockWebApplication(name="my-app")
@PrepareForTest(value = {
    Role.class
})
public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule powerMockRule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initSpring();
        mockRoleServices();
    }

    private void mockRoleServices() throws Exception {
        spy(Role.class);
        RoleAnswer roleAnswer = new RoleAnswer(RoleEnum.ADMIN);
        when(Role.hasAdministratorRole(anyLong(), anyLong(), anyLong()))
            .then(roleAnswer);
    }

    private class RoleAnswer implements Answer<Boolean> {

        private RoleEnum roleEnum;

        private RoleAnswer(RoleEnum roleEnum) {
            this.roleEnum = roleEnum;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return getRenderRequest().getUserRole() != null &&
                    getRenderRequest().getUserRole().equals(roleEnum);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the problem : the method `Role.hasAdministratorRole()` is called instead of being mocked

Here's what I tried so far :

- Using `mockStatic(Role.class)` instead of the `spy()` method. As expected, all methods are mocked, so I end up getting an NPE before `Role.hasAdministratorRole()` is called
- Doing something like `doAnswer(...).when(...)`. I get a runtime error with powermock telling me my mock is not complete (which actually confirms that something's wrong either with my code or with the lib itself)
- Trying to declare the method by its name rather than calling it directly : `when(Role.class, "hasAdministratorRole", long.class, long.class, long.class)`. Same behavior
- A bunch of other things I don't recall anymore.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks !

**EDIT** : Thanks to SrikanthLingala's answer, I was able to pinpoint the problem.

This didn't work :

```
when(Role.hasAdministratorRole(anyLong(), anyLong(), anyLong()))
    .thenAnswer(roleAnswer);
```

but this did :

```
doAnswer(roleAnswer).when(Role.class, "hasSiteAdministratorRole",
    anyLong(), anyLong(), anyLong());
```

So switching then `when()` and the `answer()` worked

Comment: Also, I noted that the class I'm trying to mock is in a jar in the classpath, (i.e not directly in the classpath). Can this be relevant ?

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't run the test with PowerMockRunner?

Comment: Other mocks work, because I'm using PowerMockRule. But anyway, I tested it, and I got exactly the same output :(

Answer (score 2):

As I do not have all of your implementations, I setup some dummy implementations and made a similar setup like yours. The below code works fine for me.

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = {
    Role.class
})
public class RoleTest {

    @Test
    public void mockRoleServices() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Role.class);
        PowerMockito.doAnswer(new RoleAnswer(RoleEnum.ADMIN)).when(Role.class, "hasAdministratorRole", Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyLong());

        Role.printOut();

        assertTrue(Role.hasAdministratorRole(1, 1, 1));
    }

    private class RoleAnswer implements Answer<Boolean> {

        private RoleEnum roleEnum;

        private RoleAnswer(RoleEnum roleEnum) {
            this.roleEnum = roleEnum;
        }

        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Dummy Role class:

```
public class Role {

    public static Boolean hasAdministratorRole(long a, long b, long c) {
        System.out.println("Inside hasAdministratorRole");
        return a + b + c < 0;
    }

    public static void printOut() {
        System.out.println("Inside Printout");
    }

}
```

My test case does not printout `Inside hasAdministratorRole`, but prints out `Inside Printout`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to test it. I was able to make it work with classes directly in my classpath (i.e. not in a jar). Could you please try to put your dummy classes in a jar, and re-test them ? I begin to think the problem comes from that.

Comment: Works fine for me even from a jar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to make it work. I edited my question to add the answer, but I don't really get why this works. Do you have an hint ? Again, thanks for your precious help

Answer (score 1):

Glad you have solved your issue, this just a warning for everyone else having a similar issue.

**Project setup:**

- Powermock 1.5.5
- Mockito 1.9.5
- TestNG 6.8.8

Powermock is not taking into account mocks/spies created in a method annotated with **@BeforeTest**

E.g.:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup(){
    testee = mock(AClass.class);
}
```

It gets discarded and then it is entering the mocked method instead of returning the expected result OR throwing all kinds of strange exceptions. When moved to a common test method, it suddenly starts working:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    AClass testee = mock(AClass.class);
    ....
}
```

Possibly it is a bug.

Comment: Issue created: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=502&thanks=502&ts=1403765338